# Android-ListImages will change continuously using Asynchronous Image loader in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, image-loading

I have used an AsyncTask class to download and load images in listview asynchronously. But I have facing a problem which is the images of each row in the listvew will change continuously. Can anyone tell how to solve this problem and set the images to the right row position after loading?

**ImageDownloaderTask class (AsyncTask)**

```
class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
// Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {

                        if (bitmap != null) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } else {
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder_gaan));
                        }
                }

        }
}

static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                                        + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                        return null;
                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        try {
                                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                                return bitmap;
                        } finally {
                                if (inputStream != null) {
                                        inputStream.close();
                                }
                                entity.consumeContent();
                        }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
                // IllegalStateException
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
        } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                        client.close();
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemRow> {

    Context context; 
    public MenuAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<ItemRow> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtBengTitle;
        TextView txtArtist;
        TextView txtTotalSongs;
        ImageView thumbImage;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ItemRow rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtBengTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bengaliTitle);
            holder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbAlbum);
            holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.txtTotalSongs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalSongs);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.txtBengTitle.setText(rowItem.getBengaliTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(rowItem.getArtist());
        holder.txtTotalSongs.setText(rowItem.getTotalSongs());
        String imageUrl = rowItem.getImage();
        if (holder.thumbImage != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.thumbImage).execute(imageUrl);
        }


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called lazy loading of images, this is quite small problem. Solutions are here:

1. https://code.google.com/p/avoiding-lazyloading-of-images-in-listview-and-gridview/
   or
2. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, could you please tell me what is the problem in my code?

Comment: It's not problem with your code. it's list view problem, it recycles continuously

Comment: then how to stop that recycling for one row image?

Comment: There is no way to stop recycling them. It's their default property

Comment: Okay, could you please give the instructions how to use the AvoidingLazyLoadingOfImages.jar for my listview (following your first link)

Comment: There are some steps in the link I have shared

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/avoiding-lazyloading-of-images-in-listview-and-gridview/source/browse/trunk/StarDataAdapter.java

Comment: see the above link, how i have used a jar file for my image view

Comment: Okay, one last query, are the belows lines enough to fulfill my task?

public LazyLoadingOfImages imageLoader;...

 imageLoader=new LazyLoadingOfImages(activity.getApplicationContext());

imageLoader.DisplayImage(stardata.getPicture(), sqView.img);

Comment: And should I have to use getBitmapFromURL() method? if yes, where??

Comment: Better you go with universal image loader, it's quite easy to use, there you can directly enter image url

Answer (score 1):

you need a mechanism to know if the view hasn’t been recycled once you’re done with the async operation.

Try to implement this pattern to track item is visible or not

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    ...

    holder.position = position;

    new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
            .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask {
    private int mPosition;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;

    public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Download bitmap here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            mHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public int position;
}
```

For good ref on ListView look at this[Performance Tips for Android’s ListView](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Comment: thanks for your response, could you please tell how to send url parameter to the ThumbnailTask class and how to use download bitmap from that url in doInBackground method? (As a novice android programmer, please consider my silly query)

Comment: You can do same as you have done in your code AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have got a simple solution by using the following open source library which is very easy to use without using ImageDownloaderTask class.

[Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Answer (score 0):

I believe You are running into problems because of the order in which the download of images is getting complete. You need stop the download of previous image while scrolling the new one to view. Here is the helpful tutorial for this

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

You should read "Handling concurrency" section of this.